# GetEmails collection script (from Retention.com) is not firing consistently through GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, webflow, google-tag-manager-server-side

I'm trying to run the collection (GetEmails) script on our site, aventure.vc. It's a website built using Webflow.

THE ISSUE: After moving the Retention script to GTM, we have received multiple emails from Retention informing us that no data has been collected for 3 or more days since it was was moved to GTM.

How can we get the script to fire consistently on our page through GTM?

---

*This is the tag configuration using the code snippet provided to us for collection by Retention.com*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOipt.jpg

*The above tag is present in the live version of the container and is shown to be firing successfully every time when checked using the "preview" option in GTM.*

Viewing the data on the Retention dashboard confirms that no data is being collected on most days, but on a few days a small number of entries are being collected.

*This Indicates that the script is firing succesfully sometimes through GTM but it is not consistently firing for everyone that visits the site.*

As a next step, on the aventure.vc website we used the "inspect" option on chrome, to view the site elements tab.

There we use the "ctrl-f" search option to manually look for the GetEmails collection script to see if it has been loaded into the site succesfully by GTM.

Upon doing this we observed that the GetEmails script does show up in the site elements sometimes,

**but in most cases when the site is loaded, the script does not appear when we look for it manually.**

---

**TL;DR**

The GetEmails script is firing everytime when put in the headers tag through webflow for our site aventure.vc,

but when trying to fire the same script through GTM, the script is missing from the site elements **most** of the time. Indicating the script does fire successfully sometimes.

**How can we get the script to fire consistently on our page through GTM?**

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more debugging.

1. Make sure you've published your GTM workspace.
2. Make sure GTM loads the CHTML tag on the page whenever you test it.
3. Check the Network tab in the dev tools to see if the call is being sent to the vendor's endpoint.
4. Check your all pages trigger. Make sure that real pageview occurs. It will not fire on SPA history changes.
5. Finally, use the GTM preview debugger for your GTM logic debugging. It will give much more insight into what's happening.